# Posting date values in REST service will not create date fields in the Domino back end

Tags: angularjs, rest, xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm creating an AngularJS HTML app using Domino in the back-end. The communication is 100% rest-based via DDS
When I send date values they don't get converted to date items on the Domino document. The values are always stored as strings
I have tried various formats on the date string with no luck
Does anyone know is this is even possible with the Domino Data Services ?
I'm using Angulars $http service with the PATCH method to update changed values only

Comment: Can you add a sample what you DDS/get and what you DDS/post?

Comment: Don't think the GET i relevant here, but this is how I Post (PATCH) my data.   data : {"releasedengmechanical1":"2014-12-18"} url: myserver:82/app/pp.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/… –

Comment: I have tried various variants of the date string with no luck. Dates are stored as text in the database

Comment: Edit your question and add the code. Improves the odds of a reply. Add both

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to store/ update a data in a document using Domino Data Services.

To get it to work you need to send the date as a string in [ISO 8601 Extended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. That's the format that the `toISOString()` function returns in JavaScript for a `Date` object. On the form that you're trying to create or update, you'll need to have that field added as a `Date/Time` field. Adding the `computewithform` parameter to the request isn't required.

Here's a sample JSON object that, when send as a `POST` or `PATCH` request to DDS, will create/ update the `LastVisit` field as a DateTime field (assuming that field is on the form).

```
{
  "FirstName":"Barney", 
  "LastName":"Bloomberg", 
  "LastVisit" : "2013-12-21T12:18:18Z"
}
```

Comment: Hi Mark. Thank you. This is one of the alternatives that I tested, but it don't work in my environment. I do my testing with Chrome and the Postman extention now ( I guess any REST client will do ) here is a linkt to a pdf I beleive illustrate the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96031701/rest-dates2.pdf

Comment: Referring to a field defined on the form does actually create a date value
However, this is causing a new and more serious problem. The date value is not interpreted correctly
1) if I send 2014-02-20T12:18:18Z , the date stored is 20’th of February as expected
2) If I send 2014-02-03T12:18:18Z , the date stored will be 2’nd of Mars !!
It seems to me that the server side wants to use the last date value in the string as the month part. 
When that is not possible (as in example 1) it tries to create a date “one way or the other” and therefore selects 20 as the date and 02 as month.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, what did you do in the end @GunnarAlmas ?

Comment: Sigh.... code developed by Americans :-(  I have had that issue with e.g. webservices as well. Really annoying!!

Answer (score 0):

The field name in the json string must be **EXACTLY** as on the form.
I had the similar problem where I had a field called 'TTL' on the form but my json generated by API using a class the field was named 'ttl'.

This resulted in a String as value for the date field, not a date.

Answer (score 0):

This works :-)

I have extended the sample that I used in [my presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/JohnDalsgaard/restful-services-on-ibm-dominoxwork-sutol-11-nov-2015-in-prague) in the following way:

Added a field "WakeupTime" on the form. Set it to Date/Time, and select to display date and time. The sample output is `08-01-2016 16:11:42`.

So reading the sample data using this url:

`.../json.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/33735D0BCE799E01C1257CC3007A7221`

I get something like this back:

```
{
  "@href": "/demo/json.nsf/api/data/documents/unid/33735D0BCE799E01C1257CC3007A7221",
  "@unid": "33735D0BCE799E01C1257CC3007A7221",
  "@noteid": "902",
  "@created": "2014-04-23T22:17:26Z",
  "@modified": "2016-01-08T15:09:57Z",
  "@authors": [
    "Anonymous",
    "CN=John Dalsgaard/O=D-D"
  ],
  "@form": "Person",
  "Unid": "33735D0BCE799E01C1257CC3007A7221",
  "Key": "33735D0BCE799E01C1257CC3007A7221",
  "Name": "Peter Hansen",
  "Email": "ph@mail.dk",
  "YearBorn": 1955,
  "WakeupTime": "2016-08-01T05:33:10Z"
}
```

Important! - this gives me the exact format that I need to use for the WakeupTime field!

So if I then post a `PATCH` back with select fields:

```
{
    "Email":"peter.hansen@mail.dk",
    "YearBorn":1953,
    "WakeupTime":"2016-01-08T05:33:40Z"
}
```

... and re-read the data then the fields are updated. And if I check in the Notes client I can see that the field is a date/time field :-)

Same happens if I create a new entry/document - the field is still the right type.

You have to be very aware of how you handle timezones though! The data are transferred as `GMT` :-)